# Does AWS Auto scaling group adds volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services

After we configure Auto scaling group and activate it, one more ec2 instance adds up. Does auto scaling creates volume as well while creating ec2 instance? If no, Which volume the newly created instance attached to?

Comment: Sashi: remember to tick the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will create new volumes depending to the AMI used in the [auto scaling launch configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLaunchConfiguration.html). If your AMI has for example two volumes configured by default, it will spawn copies of those for each new EC2 instance launched in the auto scaling group. Note that volumes cannot be simultaneously attached to multiple EC2 instances.

Comment: And if the added ec2 instance will get deleted depending on ASG configuration. Does the volume associated to it gets deleted?

Comment: This is configurable: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#preserving-volumes-on-termination